# How to set a video as a background on React Native

Tags: react-native, video, expo

I want to set a video as a background but I just could set a video on the screen, not as a background, and I want to have some buttons on it.

I have seen some questions but using react-native video library, and I am using

```
import { Video } from 'expo';
```

I want to play a video as a background with expo library, hope somebody can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve it using zIndex, following code will render video as background and play button on top of it. React native styling works same as web CSS, You should read more about css positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

```
 render() {
   return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
        <Text>Play</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Video style={styles.video} />
    </View>
   );
  }

  const styles = {
    container: {
     position: 'relative'
    },
    video: {
     position: 'absolute',
     top: 0,
     right: 0,
     left: 0,
     bottom: 0,
     zIndex: 1,
    },
    button: {
      position: 'relative',
      zIndex: 2,
    }
 };
```